# cluster a set of rectangles according to their shape or aspect ratio

Tags: cluster-analysis

I have a set of rectangles. I know the length of shorter side and longer slide of those rectangles, now I want to to divide this rectangles in a few clusters so that rectangles belongs to a particular cluster should be as similar as possible i.e their aspect ratio remains within a range within a cluster..

which clustering algorithm can I use?

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract approprite features (e.g. aspect ratio).
2. Run clustering.
3. Profit!